# Android: app crashes when list item number does not match list number

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am attempting to adapt a single shopping list into multiple shopping lists, which the user can then select a list from a list of lists, then individual products within the list.

The app performs correctly with a single list.

When loading a product from a list, the app will load the product if the product index number matches the list index number, e.g.

product 2 in list 2 will load the product, and I can then page back and forth through the list.

Attempting to load a product with an index value that does not match the lists index value, e.g. product 3 in list 2 etc will crash the app with:

```
05-17 14:46:51.029: E/AndroidRuntime(12888): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-17 14:46:51.029: E/AndroidRuntime(12888):    at com.example.testmylists.ProductFragment.onCreateView(ProductFragment.java:64)
```

ProductFragment.java

```
39      callingFragment = getActivity().getIntent()
40              .getStringExtra("start_product_pager_activity_id");
41      
42      shoppingListId = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_SHOPPING_LIST_ID, 0);
43      
44      if (callingFragment != null) {
45          
46              if (callingFragment.equals("ShoppingListFragment")) {
47              mProduct = MyLists.get(getActivity()).getShoppingList(shoppingListId)
48                          .getProduct(productId); 
49          }
50      }
51  }
52  
53  
54  @Override
55  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
56          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
57      View userView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, parent, false);
58      
59      mProductDetails = (TextView) userView.findViewById(R.id.product_details);
60      String displayInfo = "";
61      
62      if(callingFragment != null) { 
63      
64          if ((mProduct.getAisleNumber() != null) && (mProduct.getBay() != 0) && 
65                  (mProduct.getShelf() != 0)) {
```

ShoppingListProductPagerActivity.java

```
27      @TargetApi(11)
28      @Override
29      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
30          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
31          mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
32      mViewPager.setId(R.id.viewPager);
33         setContentView(mViewPager);
34
35          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
36              getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
37         }
38          
39          id =  (UUID)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("shopping_list_id");
40          mShoppingList = MyLists.get(this).getShoppingList(id);
41      
42         FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
43      
44          mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragManager) {
45
46          @Override           
47             public int getCount() {
48                  return mShoppingList.size();    
49              }
50              @Override
51              public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
52                      UUID productId = mShoppingList.get(pos).getId();
53              return ProductFragment.newInstance(productId);
54              }
55         });
```

ShoppingListFragment.java

```
122 @Override
123 public void onListItemClick(ListView lView, View view, int position, long id) {
124     
125     Product mProduct = (Product) (getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
126     Log.d(TAG, "item " + mProduct.getProductDescription());
127     
128     Intent productFragment = new Intent(getActivity(), ShoppingListProductPagerActivity.class);
129     productFragment.putExtra("start_product_pager_activity_id", "ShoppingListFragment");
130     productFragment.putExtra(ProductFragment.EXTRA_SHOPPING_LIST_ID, position);
131     productFragment.putExtra(ProductFragment.EXTRA_PRODUCT_ID, mProduct.getId());
132     productFragment.putExtra("shopping_list_id", items.getShoppingListId());
133     Log.d(TAG, "Item clicked" + mProduct.getProductDescription());
134     
135     startActivity(productFragment);
136 }
```

I think the problem exists somewhere in these code blocks for ShoppingListProductPagerActivity or ShoppingListFragment.

MyLists is a singleton class that stores an ArrayList of shopping lists.

Comment: What is `MyLists`? What is it's scope and values in it? Your `mProduct ` should be null, so need to know about `MyLists`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
productFragment.putExtra(ProductFragment.EXTRA_SHOPPING_LIST_ID, position);
```

in ShoppingListFragment.java was replaced with:

```
productFragment.putExtra(ProductFragment.EXTRA_SHOPPING_LIST_UUID, shoppingListId.toString());
```

Added this method in MyLists.java

```
    public ShoppingList getShoppingListViaId(UUID id) {
    for (ShoppingList sL : myLists) {
        if (sL.getShoppingListId().equals(id)) {
            return sL;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Changed this code in productFragment.java

```
shoppingListId = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_SHOPPING_LIST_ID, 0);

if (callingFragment != null) {

if (callingFragment.equals("ShoppingListFragment")) {
mProduct = MyLists.get(getActivity()).getShoppingList(shoppingListId)
.getProduct(productId); 
 }
}
```

to:

```
        shoppingListId = UUID.fromString(getActivity().getIntent()
                    .getStringExtra(EXTRA_SHOPPING_LIST_UUID));

    if (callingFragment != null) {

        if (callingFragment.equals("ShoppingListFragment")) {
            mProduct = MyLists.get(getActivity()).getShoppingListViaId(shoppingListId)
                    .getProduct(productId); 
        }
    }
```

In short, was attempting to pass an int to identfy a shoppinglist when I should have been passing a UUID.